# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden in Asp.net C# Instagram.(HttpWebRequest)

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, webclient, instagram

When I access

```
response = request.GetResponse();// request is a HttpWebRequest's object
```

The remote server returned an error: `(403) Forbidden. error`. But when i execute the url in the request in my browser URL, it gets redirected to the page which I specified.

Here's the complete code.

```
string newPostLink = string.Format("https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={0}&amp;redirect_uri=http://localhost:2163/Main.aspx&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=basic", clientId); 

HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(newPostLink); 

request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
request.Referer = newPostLink;
request.Method = "POST"; 
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0)";
request.Accept = "/"; 
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 

if (request.Proxy != null)
{ 
  request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
} 

var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: This might because you need to pass oauth details. When you use the browser you're probably logged in already

Comment: @MarkPM I have already passed the details (ClientId,RedirectUri,response_type,scope).

Comment: Show us the full request code

Comment: string newPostLink = string.Format(
                    "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:2163/Main.aspx&;response_type=code&scope=basic", clientId);                                                          HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(newPostLink);

Comment: request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Referer = newPostLink;request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0)";request.Accept = "*/*";
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;               request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;              
if (request.Proxy != null){                   request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}  var response = request.GetResponse();

Comment: @Murali I took the code in the comment and posted it in the question, so it's easier to read. Please review it and format / correct as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to UserAgent string you are sending in WebRequest.
You can try to change UserAgent string to simulate that request is coming from Firefox to see if it works then.

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US), is the UserAgent string i am using.